# Adding condition to js function to secure Stripe function to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the different scripts that i use on my webpages, i found one that is modifying iframe sources. One page contains the new stripe checkout snippet that is using iframes. This iframe being modified, clicking on Stripe button doesn't get end-user to stripe checkout page of my product.
So i wish to know how to modify this function adding a condition avoiding to modify sources that includes "https://js.stripe.com/" as all Stripe's iframe have their sources starting with it.
Here is the code i need to modify:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("iframe").each(function(){
        var ifr_source = $(this).attr('src');
        var wmode = "wmode=transparent";
        if(ifr_source.indexOf('?') != -1) {
        var getQString = ifr_source.split('?');
        var oldString = getQString[1];
        var newString = getQString[0];
        $(this).attr('src',newString+'?'+wmode+'&'+oldString);
        }
        else $(this).attr('src',ifr_source+'?'+wmode);
    });
});
```

thank you for your help, i hope that this post is more consistent with the rules Rafael pointed

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Stripe support reported the issue to development team and got stripe's script modified to avoid the issue, so this issue is not a blocking issue anymore, but the probleme to add a condition to this code still stands.